# Mongo Query to retrieve friends

Tags: mongodb

Currently, I have these two collections.
[image]

[image]

I am checking if either my *_id* matches the *requestor_id* or the *recipient_id* and *status* is 1 after the aggragation. I get three objects from this and I'm only suppose to get one. Below is my code.

```
//myID
var user_id = req.body.user_id;

dbo.collection('User_List').aggregate([
{$lookup:{
    from:'Friendship',
    pipeline:[{
          $match:{
             $expr:{
                 $and:[{
                    $or:[
                       {$eq:['$requester_id',user_id]},
                       {$eq:['$recipient_id',user_id]}
                        ]},
                    {$eq:['$status',1]}
                      ]}
                   }
                 }
              ],
    as:'friends'}},
    {$unwind:'$friends' }]).toArray(function(err,data){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log((data));
            db.close();
        });
```

If there is a better schema to how I should organize my collection, please let me know as well. Thank you in advance for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), to get friends of a specific user.

```
//myID
var user_id = req.body.user_id;

dbo.collection('User_List').aggregate([
{$match: { '_id': ObjectId(user_id)}},
{$lookup:{
    from:'Friendship',
    pipeline:[{
          $match:{
             $expr:{
                 $and:[{
                    $or:[
                       {$eq:['$requester_id',user_id]},
                       {$eq:['$recipient_id',user_id]}
                        ]},
                    {$eq:['$status',1]}
                      ]}
                   }
                 }
              ],
    as:'friends'}},
    {$unwind:'$friends' }]).toArray(function(err,data){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log((data));
            db.close();
        });
```

Comment: I used match and I am able to get the specific friends. This time, I am left with data from the Friendship collection. From there, I have to do another lookup based on the id in either requester_id or recipient_id that do not equal to my ID. Any clue?